# Mod Rewrite to remove language from url in Concrete5 cms

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo, concrete5

I'm totally stumped. Hope you can help. I just spent a month redeveloping our website in Concrete5 version 7.3.1, latest version, and I'm ready to launch. It's a multi-lingual site and our SEO guy recommended not to include the language in the URL for the default language (English) as it would change our homepage from domain.com/ to domain.com/en/, and our old site default language was in the base directory.

Concrete5 doesn't support this so basically I'm hoping to accomplish this with some .htaccess trickery, but am getting no where.

Concrete5 urls are domain.com/index.php/en/path/to/page, so all pages are fed off index.php. There is a rewrite rule as follows to hide the index.php from the user and make the urls pretty.

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
#RewriteRule . index.php
```

I want to further add a way to add the /en/ for the server side from a url which doesn't include it. i.e.

```
RewriteRule ^/index.php/(.*) ^/index.php/en/$1 [L]
```

So I can then strip the en from the urls and the system will still work.

I've tried putting this before concrete's rewrite (without index.php), after, and multiple different combinations, but keep getting a 401 error and it's hard to diagnose the problem as it's not so easy to see the generated url.

Any help would be much appreciated as I've got to figure this out before launch.

Comment: This is not something that you will be able to do without a lot of work and a very temperamental `.htaccess`, there isn't any SEO issue with having your site at `/en` in fact that will might actually improve your ranking. That said, what version of concrete5 are you using?

Comment: If you wanted /en to be the only one that resolves at the root of the domain, depending on the size of the site, you could always add additional paths to the pages that resolve at a path without the /en. I realize that might not be a practical solution, but it would do the trick :) EDIT: That is, add paths through the CMS, in page properties.

Comment: Hi Korvin, yes agreed, there's no SEO issue with having the root at /en, but there is with moving from a site which used to have the root at /, and then changing it to /en. I can do a 301 redirect, but still will lose some 'link juice' as my SEO guy puts it. I'm using Concrete5 5.7.3.1.

Comment: coupdecoop, Thanks for that, but I haven't found a way of getting Concrete5 to resolve a path which is at the root. I.e. concrete5 has a root home page, which redirects to /en/, which has my real home page. If I add a path to resolve at /, I either get shown the dummy home page, not my real one, or I get stuck in a redirect loop.

Comment: @a575606 I believe @coupdecoup was talking more about the subpages like `/en/example` could me made to show at `/example`, still I'm not sure that 301 redirects will harm your page rank in any way. Sites move around constantly and google isn't stupid. I'm not aware of any way that you'll be able to achieve this without pain and code, for instance; Is `/de` going to resolve to the german homepage, or to `/en/de`?

Answer (score 1):

With [this recently added event](https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5-5.7.0/commit/4a9149930eb6ed523fa4a3c2139c58dae887aea4) in the new 5.7.4 version that is to come out sometime soon, we're able to do some interesting things with the request. One thing we can do is ensure the page at that path doesn't exist, then rewrite the request to make it look to concrete5 that the request is actually coming in to `/en`.

```php
\Events::addListener('on_before_dispatch', function() {
    $request = \Request::getInstance();
    $page = \Page::getByPath($request->getPath()); // Get the real requested page

    if ($page->isError()) { // If it doesn't exist
        $path = new \Concrete\Core\Url\Components\Path($request->getPath());
        $path = $path->prepend('en'); // prepend "/en" to the path, ex: "/path/to" becomes "/en/path/to"

        $page = Page::getByPath($path);
        if (!$page->isError) { // Make sure that this page actually exists
            // This may not work, you might need to replace the actual \Request instance.
            $request->setCurrentPage($page); // Set it to the requested page. 
        }
    }
});
```

---

I really suggest that you do not do this. As described in my comments on the question, you'll run into really weird cases that will cause SEO issues and general routing issues in your site.

---

**Edit:** concrete5 version 8 includes HTTP middleware, which is a better solution to this problem.

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need. What is a good place to put this in? One of the config files or is there a better spot?

Comment: The best place to put this is `/application/bootstrap/app.php`

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!